# Is it possible to modify linux mount defaults option?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, mount

Is it possible to modify/redefine linux mount defaults option?

For example, having a fstab like this:

```
# / was on /dev/sda8 during installation
UUID=669cb10d /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=43e81f24 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
```

Is it possible to redefine the "defaults" option?

I know that it's usually defined like this:

defaults: rw, suid, dev, exec, auto, nouser, and async. [see man mount](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount)

Answer (score 5):

There seems to be *some* support for setting default mount options for ext4 using tune2fs.

The syntax is something like `tune2fs -E mount_opts=.. device`

More info here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab and in `man tune2fs`

Comment: Yes, something like this is what I was looking for. Although it's not enough for my need... "superblock setting is only honored in 2.6.35+ kernels; and not at all by the ext2 and ext3 file system drivers."

Answer (score -1):

You can define options for mounting block devices in /etc/fstab.

for example:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# The root filesystem should have a pass number of either 0 or 1.
# All other filesystems should have a pass number of 0 or greater than 1.
#

#                           

LABEL=geee      /       ext4        relatime    0 1
LABEL=usr       /usr        ext4        relatime    0 2
LABEL=var       /var        ext4        relatime    0 2
LABEL=portage       /usr/portage    reiserfs    noatime     0 0
#LABEL=it2901       /it2901     ext4        relatime    0 2
LABEL=home      /home       ext4        relatime    0 2
LABEL=boot      /boot       ext3        noatime     0 2
/dev/sda1       /mnt/win    ntfs-3g uid=1512,umask=0022     0 0
/dev/sda3       /mnt/media  ntfs-3g uid=1512,umask=0022 0 0
/mnt/media/media    /media      none        bind        0 0
/dev/sda6       none        swap        sw      0 0

#/dev/sda5      /mnt/ubuntu     ext3        noatime     0 0
#/mnt/ubuntu/boot   /boot       none        bind        0 0
/mnt/media/root-extension/usr/share/doc /usr/share/doc none bind    0 0

genja.lan:/R/tmp        /R/tmp      nfs         noauto,nfsvers=3,soft,intr 0 0
#genja.lan:/R/es2       /R/es2      nfs         noauto,soft,intr 0 0
#genja.lan:/R/mirror    /R/mirror   nfs         noauto,soft,intr 0 0
##raptor.lan:/usr/portage /usr/portage  nfs         noauto,soft,intr 0 0
tryggve.lan:/R/tb   /R/tb       nfs         noauto,nfsvers=3,soft,intr 0 0
#tryggve.lan:/R/audio   /R/audio    nfs         noauto,soft,intr 0 0

tmpfs           /tmp        tmpfs size=200M,nodev,nosuid,noexec 0 0
shm         /dev/shm    tmpfs       nodev,nosuid,noexec 0 0
```

[image: gentoo fstab]